# "RUN-TIME error '3085' Undefined Function 'EMAIL' in expression"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access VBA code to automatically send emails through Outlook after a set amount of time.

I keep getting a run-time error 3085. I do not know what went wrong or what function it is referring to. Is it possibly a reference I am missing or did I mess up on my functions somewhere?

```
Option Compare Database
Sub SendMail()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Dim emailTo As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outlookStarted As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outApp Is Nothing Then
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outlookStarted = True
End If

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT DATE, COMPANY, CUSTOMER, EMAIL(DISTRIBUTOR), FUP" & _
  " FROM Sample Query WHERE DATE = (Date())"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until rs.EOF

  emailTo = Trim(rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value & " " & _
    rs.Fields("CUSTOMER").Value) & _
    " <" & rs.Fields("EMAIL(DISTRIBUTOR)").Value & ">"

  emailSubject = "Proposal Follow Up"
  If IsNull(rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value) Then
      emailSubject = emailSubject & " for " & _
        rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value & " " & rs.Fields("CUSTOMER").Value
  End If

  emailText = Trim("Hello " & rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value) & "!" & vbCrLf

  emailText = emailText & _
    "We put an order on " & rs.Fields("DATE").Value & _
    " for " & rs.Fields("COMPANY").Value & _
    "A follow up would be good about now"

  Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  outMail.To = emailTo
  outMail.Subject = emailSubject
  outMail.Body = emailText
  outMail.Send

  rs.Edit
  rs("FUP") = Now()
  rs.Update

  rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

If outlookStarted Then
    outApp.Quit
End If

Set outMail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EMAIL(DISTRIBUTOR)` needs to be surrounded by brackets to be a valid.

> ```
> strSQL = "SELECT DATE, COMPANY, CUSTOMER, [EMAIL(DISTRIBUTOR)]
> ```

Comment: Or better yet, use `PascalCase` column names in your tables, and when that's not possible, use `PascalCase` aliases for them, that way they don't need to be square-bracketed! =)

Comment: Hear Hear!! Or should I say "Quack Quack!"?